# how to initialize a 2D vector C++

Tags: c++, class, vector

I'm a beginner in C++.

I'm trying to make a Matrix class by my own to train me.
I declared in my `class Matrix` `std::vector<std::vector<long>> m_data;` whitch is a 2D vector to store my numbers. In a constructor I want to initialize my 2D array with 2 arguments : `NbRows` and `NbCols`. I'm stuck there.

```
Matrix::Matrix(unsigned int nb_row, unsigned int nb_col) 

{
    int i, j;
    m_nbRow = nb_row;
    m_nbCol = nb_col;

    for(i = 0; i < m_nbCol; i ++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j <m_nbRow; j ++)
        {
            // ?????
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Vectors don't have a fixed size. They are sized as needed, typically when using `push_back()`. Use `std::array` if you want a fixed array size. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Comment: This is also a good place to use a [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Comment: This has been asked many, many times. Please research before asking so that we are not repeating ourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to resize the outer vector before the first `for` loop.

The inner vector can be resized and then assigned to, or items pushed back to it.

```
Matrix::Matrix(unsigned int nb_row, unsigned int nb_col) 
{
    int i, j;
    m_nbRow = nb_row;
    m_nbCol = nb_col;

    m_data.resize(m_nbCol);
    for(i = 0; i < m_nbCol; i ++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j <m_nbRow; j ++)
        {
            m_data[i].push_back(<some value>);
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
Matrix::Matrix(unsigned int nb_row, unsigned int nb_col) 
{
    int i, j;
    m_nbRow = nb_row;
    m_nbCol = nb_col;

    m_data.resize(m_nbCol);
    for(i = 0; i < m_nbCol; i ++)
    {
        m_data[i].resize(m_nbRow);
        for(j = 0; j <m_nbRow; j ++)
        {
            m_data[i][j] = <some value>;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to initialize the elements of the matrix to zero, you can simplify it to:

```
Matrix::Matrix(unsigned int nb_row, unsigned int nb_col) 
{
    m_nbRow = nb_row;
    m_nbCol = nb_col;
    m_data.resize(m_nbCol, std::vector<long>(m_nbRow));
}
```

**PS**

Normally, the first index of matrix corresponds to a row while the second index corresponds to a column. You are using them the other way around in your post. I assume you have a reason for that.

Answer (score 3):

A simple one-line solution is as follows:

```
Matrix(unsigned int nb_row, unsigned int nb_col){
    m_data = std::vector<std::vector<long>>(nb_row, std::vector<long>(nb_col,0));
}
```

You can replace the "0" with any other number, depending on what you wish to initialise your matrix to.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest solution ever:

```
Matrix(unsigned int nb_row, unsigned int nb_col) : m_nbrow(nb_row), m_nbcol(nb_col), 
     m_data(nb_row, vector<int>(nb_col)) {}
```

NB `vector` of `vector`s is probably not the best idea as it will create double indirection and it will store and check redundant copies of the inner matrix dimension size (i.e. the size of inner `vector`s), not to mention the non-sequential layout.

A more common approach is one `vector` of a size `nb_row*nb_col` with some usual syntactic trickery for indexing - `index = nb_col*y + x`.